# Leaking Outdoor Faucet

Tags: plumbing

I have an outdoor facet that leaks through the front of the turning mechanism.  I have tried to remove the whole front of the facet by turning the nut shaped piece in the middle (where the blue arrow is pointing).  It does not budge (or look like its meant to be moved).  Any suggestion to remove the front of the faucet so i can see what happening on the inside (e.g., old washer).  Pictures below.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two wrenches (one to **hold the body of the valve** so you don't rip the screws out and twist the pipe behind it) and they should be **large** (2 foot long handles would be entirely normal) and the one used on the nut should be an actual smooth jaw wrench that fits it, not whatever has been tried on it that left scars. It's absolutely meant to be removed, but it's been out in the weather a while. You need more leverage.

However, if you can get the rusty screw holding the handle on out (and go find a stainless steel or brass replacement for it) you should find a smaller "packing nut" which is what you actually need to either tighten *slightly*, or remove, replace the valve stem packing, and retighten. Valve stem packing is what makes a seal that rotating parts such as the valve stem can still move within (at the proper tightness - too loose, it leaks, too tight, the handle won't move.) If tightening it somewhat won't stop the leak,  new packing material may be required. A plumbing or good hardware store will have that.